# How can I utilize optional arguments for flexible Vector sizes?

Tags: optional-arguments

I have created a macro to create a size of `2 x 1`, but I would like to add an optional argument to make it `2 x 1`, or `3 x 1` depending if you choose to a third argument. The current implementation is,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Vector}{ m m}{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
                #1 \\ 
                #2
        \end{bmatrix}
    }
}
```

How could this be accomplished so that I can call `\Vector{1}{2}` or `\Vector{1}{2}{3}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Vector}{mmo}{%
  \begin{bmatrix} #1 \\ #2 \IfValueT{#3}{\\ #3} \end{bmatrix}%
}
```

but I'm not sure you really want

```
\Vector{1}{2}  \Vector{1}{2}[3]
```

which is difficult to see in the typescript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Vector}{mmo}{%
  \begin{bmatrix} #1 \\ #2 \IfValueT{#3}{\\ #3} \end{bmatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Vector{1}{2} \quad \Vector{1}{2}[3]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find that its much simpler to manage lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Vector}{m}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \clist_use:nn { #1 } { \\ }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\Vector{1,2} \quad \Vector{1,2,3} \quad \Vector{1,2,3,4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like commas as separators and prefer, say, a semicolon, you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Vector}{m}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\Vector{1;2} \quad \Vector{1;2;3} \quad \Vector{1;2;3;4}
\]

\end{document}
```

**Note** I removed `\ensuremath` that does nothing really useful in this case and in several others.
<sub>Part of my campaign DUUE (Don't Use Unnecessary Ensuremath).</sub>

Comment: Your script works well and it is what I wanted.
In Overleaf it compiles and works correctly, but I still get an error saying "Missing $ inserted" when my example use case would be `\Vector{$u_1$}{$u_2$}[$u_3$]`. Would you know why this is occurring?

Comment: @Michael Why the $ characters? The entries are already typeset in math mode.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. Is everything inside of `bmatrix` the same as if you were typing between `$`?

Answer (score 4):

Your macro can open an empty `\tmp` and then test, if the next character is `{` using `\futurelet` primitive. If this is true then the parameter is read and added to the `\tmp`. If it is false then the reading of all parameters is closed and the `\left[\matrix{\tmp}\right]` is printed.

```
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\Vector{\def\tmp{}\futurelet\next\VectorA}
\def\VectorA{\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter\VectorB \else \expandafter\VectorC\fi}
\def\VectorB#1{\addto\tmp{#1\cr}\futurelet\next\VectorA}
\def\VectorC{\left[\matrix{\tmp}\right]}

test:
$$
  \Vector{1}{2}, \Vector{2}{3}{4}, \Vector{4}{5}{6}{7}
$$
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a command `\Vector` that takes an arbitrary number of entries separated by commas. There is also an optional argument to change the spacing. Default is currently set to `3ex`, which is the distance between the baselines of the entries (not the space between). Change the value of `\vecspace` to set a different default.

[image]

Usage is `\Vector[<spacing>]{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n}`. See the code below for the examples illustrated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\vecspace}{3ex}
\newcommand{\Vector}[2][\vecspace]{\left[\tikz[baseline]{
  \foreach \c[count=\n] in {#2}{\xdef\numb{\n}}
  \foreach \c[count=\n] in {#2}{
    \node[inner sep=0, anchor=base] at (0,{(\numb/2-\n+.5)*#1}){\c};
  }}\right]
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Vector{1,2},\Vector{1,2,3},\Vector{1,2,3,4},\Vector[4ex]{1,2,3,4}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh boy that is a bit more intense that I expected, is their a much simpler version for either size 2 or 3, not extremely flexible, but with a single optional argument for size 3.

Comment: I suppose you could just define two commands that take 2 and 3 arguments respectively: `\Vector{1}{2}` and `\Vectorr{1}{2}{3}`.

Comment: Could the specifier O or o be utilized?